# How do I pay customers online?

Tags: payments, payment-gateway

Payment portals such as Paypal and Stripe let web masters accept credit card payments from customers.

Are there services that let web masters pay customers? Maybe a customer could input banking information (account number, routing) and some API lets the web master automatically transfer money?

Comment: Perhaps you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456408/how-can-i-electronically-transfer-money-to-another-account-using-bank-transfer. Numerous providers exist with API solutions if you search for 'bacs payment api'.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal gives you the 'mass pay API' (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/).